# Vue JS set default state from Vuex on app launch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm working with Nuxt JS 2.15 and Vuex. I'm building a hybrid app utilising [Capacitor JS](https://capacitorjs.com/) and need to utilise the phone's storage to persist data such as app settings and user settings on the phone. I'm using the [storage](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage) module in conjunction with Vuex in order to achieve this.

Currently, I'm able to set some default app settings in an `app_settings` state of my Vuex store and then can call an `@click` in a vue file to update an app setting like this:

```js
/*
** Update setting
*/
updateSetting (model, value) {
  this.$store.commit('storage/updateSetting', {
    key: model,
    value: value
  })
}
```

The above is tied to a button click where the `v-model` corrosponds to a setting from the store:

```html
<div v-for="(option, index) in options.theme" :key="index">
  <hr v-if="index > 0" />
  <label
    :for="`theme-${index}`"
    class="tw-flex tw-items-center tw-w-full tw-py-4 tw-px-8 tw-cursor-pointer hover:tw-bg-gray-100 active:tw-bg-gray-200 tw-h-20">
    <div class="tw-flex tw-w-full tw-items-center">
      <div class="tw-text-left">
        <h2 class="tw-font-medium lg:tw-text-lg tw-text-gray-500">{{ option.title }}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tw-ml-auto">
        <div class="tw-flex-1 tw-items-center tw-flex tw-justify-end">
          <input :id="`theme-${index}`" v-model="$store.state.storage.app_settings.theme" @change="updateSetting('theme', $store.state.storage.app_settings.theme)" :value="option.value" name="theme" type="radio" class="focus:tw-ring-indigo-600 tw-h-4 tw-w-4 tw-text-indigo-800 border-gray-300">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

When I change a setting, sure enough, my `updateSetting` mutation is running as intended, updating the Vuex store state and also setting a `CapacitorStorage.key` in my browser *(this would be the phone's storage on a physical phone)*

However, if a user changes a default setting, I need to fetch all of the settings from Capacitor's storage on app launch so that the user's desired app settings are retained.

Currently I've got a function called `setDefaultSettings` that I intend to run on app launch, and set all of the settings in the `app_settings` state.

Why isn't my function being called correctly on launch, what am I missing or need to modify here?

**store/storage.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
  app_settings: {
    theme: 'system',
    refreshButtonPlacement: 'right',
    fetchTimeout: 120
  }
})

async function getData (storage, key) {
  const { value } = await storage.get({ key: key })
  return value
}


export const mutations = {

  /*
   * Set default settings on app launch
   */
  async setDefaultSettings (state, data) {
    const theme = getData(this.$CapacitorStorage, 'theme')

    if (theme) {
      state.app_settings.theme = getData(this.$CapacitorStorage, 'theme')
    }
  },

  /*
   * Update app setting
   */
  async updateSetting (state, data) {
    state.app_settings[data.key] = data.value

    await this.$CapacitorStorage.set({
      key: data.key,
      value: data.value
    })
  },

  // TODO: set dedault settings
  setDefaultSettings()

}
```

Comment: Maybe you can call `setDefaultSettings` inside the `mounted` hook of `App.vue` ?

Comment: I'd then have to do this in each and every view surely? Which isn't really what I need

Comment: `nuxtServerInit` may be useful here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: Surely there's a way to simply call the function `setDefaultSettings ` from within my Vuex file? I ideally need to keep everything contained there for ease?

Comment: Don't use `v-model` directly on the store - use a 'local' variable, populated from the store at component creation, then just use the commit to keep the store and the variable state in sync.